# How to render svg image in node twig file?

Tags: theming, 8

How to render svg image in node twig file. The image field is in field collection.
Rendering code used

```
<img src="{{ file_url(l2web.getFieldCollectionItem().field_deployment_image2.entity.uri.value) }}" />
```

( https://www.drupal.org/node/2541480 patch used )

> But am getting issue in node twig file. Issue is
>   Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: Calling "uri" method on a 
>   "Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem" object is not
>   allowed. in
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigSandboxPolicy->checkMethodAllowed() (line 197
>   of \node--l2-page.html.twig)

Comment: Don't think this has something to do with svg. You are in the wrong object. `.entity` is not getting a image file, but another field collection.

Comment: When the image is png or jpeg no issue. Everything working fine. Later i added patches for svg upload. I can able to upload image but when seeing the page am getting issue.

Comment: You apply `.entity` on a field inside a field collection item and you get another field collection item. This looks like two nested field collections. Maybe you have used for png/jpeg one level and for svg two levels? But this is hard to tell without having a chance to look into the variable l2web.